# Sprite shadow in 3D world

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, sprite, shadow

I am trying to project shadows from sprites on 3D objects, i followed some tips here and there but i still have issues.

I created a material that use `Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Cutout/Diffuse` and add it to my sprite, i also enable `ShadowCastingMode` and `receiveShadows` on the `SpriteRenderer`.

The result is that my sprite actually cast a shadow now, but the sprite itself is also shadowed, which is not the result i am looking for.

Without the shader:
[image]

With the shader:
[image]

I know absolutely nothing about materials and shader so this is me just walking in the dark.

Also this is a brand new project and i am using the template `3D with extra` if it makes any difference.